# How to connect server side programming (c#) on html button click

Tags: c#, html, mysql

I am rookie in this.

What I am trying to do is creating a simple login and register page using Html.Then I created a database in Mysql and I am using c# as my server side programming to interact with the database.(I don't wanna use PHP)

Now I need your help on how to connect my Html page to the c# program.

Here is my html code.

```
      <div class="top-row">
        <div class="field-wrap">
          <label>
            First Name<span class="req">*</span>
          </label>
          <input type="text" required autocomplete="off" />
        </div>

        <div class="field-wrap">
          <label>
            Last Name<span class="req">*</span>
          </label>
          <input type="text"required autocomplete="off"/>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>
          Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="email"required autocomplete="off"/>
      </div>

      <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>
          Set A Password<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="password"required autocomplete="off"/>
      </div>

       <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>
          Category(Doctor/Patient)<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="text"required autocomplete="off"/>
      </div>     

      <button type="submit" class="button button-block"/>Get Started</button>        

      </form>
```

Here is my c# code

```
 namespace dbsample
 {
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    private MySqlConnection connection;
    private string server;
    private string database;
    private string uid;
    private string password;      

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Initialize();
    }            

        //Initialize values
        private void Initialize()
        {
            server = "localhost";
            database = "registerdatabase";
            uid = "root";
            password = "mysql";
            string connectionString;
            connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";
            connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        }

        //open connection to database
        private bool OpenConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                return true;
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);                       
             }
                return false;
            }
        }

        //Close connection
        private bool CloseConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }

        //Insert statement
        public void Insert()
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current!=null)
            {                          

           var first_name =HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["first_name"];
           var last_name = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["last_name"];
           var email_address = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form ["email_address"];
           var category = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["category"];;
           string query = "INSERT INTO users_db (first_name,last_name,email_address,category) VALUES("+first_name+","+last_name+","+email_address+","+category+")";

           }

            //open connection
            if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
            {
                //create command and assign the query and connection from the constructor
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

                //Execute command
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                //close connection
                this.CloseConnection();
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Insert();
        }
    }

 }
```

So, how can I connect my HTML page to c#.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider reading some basic tutorial on ASP.Net or ASP.Net MVC... It does look like you are expecting WinForm app to magically turn into web app which not going to happen...

Comment: search on button's `onClick` event to trigger the server side code. But you should go through some beginner tutorials as @AlexeiLevenkov suggested.

Comment: You have the wrong sort of project - you need to create an asp.net project - a website or web application in Visual Studio.  This will contain both the HTML and the code behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to convert your html code to asp.net web forms.

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div class="top-row">
            <div class="field-wrap">
                <label>
                    First Name<span class="req">*</span>
                </label>
                <input type="text" autocomplete="off" />
            </div>

            <div class="field-wrap">
                <label>
                    Last Name<span class="req">*</span>
                </label>
                <input type="text" autocomplete="off" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
                Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="email" autocomplete="off" />
        </div>

        <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
                Set A Password<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="password" autocomplete="off" />
        </div>

        <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
                Category(Doctor/Patient)<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" />
        </div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Get Started" CssClass="button button-block" />
    </div>
</form>
```